Excel VBA, Range return of User-defined function not working with OFFSET in formula
I'm working with ranges of data with variable length. Therefore to get the entire range, I made a short excel function:
Function UntilBlank(StartCell As Range)
Dim lastCell As Range
Dim currentCell As Range

Set lastCell = StartCell.Cells(1, 1)
Set currentCell = StartCell.Offset(1, 0)

While Not (IsEmpty(currentCell.Cells(1, 1)))
    Set lastCell = lastCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Set currentCell = lastCell.Offset(1, 0)
Wend

UntilBlank = Range(StartCell.Cells(1, 1), lastCell)

End Function

This works great for most cases. However, when I try to use this function within an OFFSET as its first parameter, OFFSET just returns a single #VALUE cell.
My expectation is the return of my function works like any other range. The .address of the return looks perfect, I just don't understand why offset is having trouble taking that range reference and offsetting it normally.

Your function doesn't actually return a range, but implicitly the value of a range. Also, While....Wend is deprecated, and you don't need a loop for this at all (use Range.End instead).

@BigBen Is there a way I can change this? I would like my function to return the range itself rather than the value so I can continue to work with the range's reference.

Consider using Function UntilBlank(StartCell As Range) As Range.

@BigBen Function UntilBlank(StartCell As Range) returns Variant which is suitable to return an error code.

@rotabor I cordially disagree with your reasoning.

@BigBen Do you disagree particularly with what: 1. Is it not the best practice to handle error? 2. Is Variant not only the return type suitable to return error from UDF?

@rotabor the implicit Variant is IMO the whole reason for this question. I like the explicitness of returning a Range and letting any calling procedure handle errors. Also, OP is likely not at the level yet to be even considering error handling. What error are you anticipating this UDF to throw?

@BigBen "the implicit Variant is IMO the whole reason for this question" - no. You can't avoid Set to perform object assignment. But, which is strange, Function UntilBlank(StartCell As Range) As Range allows to return the array not the Range.

@rotabor the implicit Variant allows the UDF in its current state to return the implicit .Value of the Range. Your last sentence is wrong, the Range is returned (obviously you need the missing Set as per your answer), but you're likely implicitly accessing its .Value.

@BigBen "Your last sentence is wrong" - truly, I failed somehow.

Three letters more will resolve your problem
Set UntilBlank = Range(StartCell.Cells(1, 1), lastCell)

Now the function returns the Range instead of an array of values.

Could you not replace the entire function with something like this? Neater, tidier and no loops to slow things down.
Function UntilBlank(StartCell As Range) As Range
    If Len(StartCell.Offset(1, 0)) = 0 Then
        Set UntilBlank = StartCell
    Else
        Set UntilBlank = Range(StartCell.Cells(1, 1), StartCell.End(xlDown))
    End If
End Function

